# foreach with sql in twig symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I have the following code in PHP:

```
$em     = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager(); 
$entity = $em->getRepository('DataBundle:SomeData')->findAll();

foreach ($entity as $item)
{
   echo $item->getSomething();

   $data = $em->getRepository('DataBundle:SomeData')
              ->findBySomeId($item->getSomeId());

   foreach ($data as $somevar)
   {
      echo $somevar->getSomeOtherData();   
   }
}
```

Can it be translated in Twig? If so, I would appreciate pointers on how it can be done.

Thanks

Comment: it's not possible. you cant find something in twig.
If you want use double cycle, you must build hash arrays or use binding between entities.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to do your entity calculations in your model, initiated by your controller and pass those objects into your View to be pushed into your Template Engine.

The Twig would look like this:

```
{% for item in entity %}
  {{ item.getSomething }}

  {% for somevar in data %}
     {{ somevar.getSomeOtherData }}
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Edit: Here's a more exacting answer you can extrapolate from here:

```
// Controller
public function demoAction()
{
    $demoModel = $this->get('demo.bundle.model.demo');
    $demoView = $this->get('demo.bundle.view.demo');
    $demoResult = $demoModel->myModelCalculation();

    return $demoView->myDemoView($demoResult);
}

//Model
public function myModelCalculation()
{
    return $this->getRepository('DataBundle:SomeData')->findAll();
}

//View
public function myDemoView($entity)
{
    return $this->getTemplatingEngine()->renderResponse('DemoBundle:demo:index.html.twig', array('entity' => $entity));
}

//Twig
{% for item in entity %}
    {{ item.getSomething }}
{% endfor %}
```

Symfony2 is easy to learn, I recommend doing their tutorials and reading the docs.
http://symfony.com/doc/current/index.html

Comment: Added some additional content/direction for you.

Comment: Symfony is not MVC framework. I think creating services for model, and view is unnecessary here. Also "data" twig variable must depend on id of "item", so it is better to use something like OneToMany doctrine association in the entity

Comment: @Ziumin, Lets see your answer. Symfony performance is not hindered in anyway by using an MVC structure and provides a better long term ability to manage the code. Albeit, you cant determine from the OP's question if this is necessary, its not wrong either.

Answer (score 0):

```
//SomeData.php
// ....
class SomeData 
{
  // ...

  /**
   * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="SomeData")
   */
  private $children;
}


//Controler
class SomeController
{
  /**
   * @Template()
   */
  public function someAction()
  {
    return ('entities' => $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('DataBundle:SomeData')->findAll());
  }
}

//some.html.twig
{% for item in entities %}
   {{ item.getSomething }}

   {% for somevar in item.children %}
      {{ somevar.getSomeOtherData }}
   {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```